# Search box that searches another site

Tags: php, search, parameters

Site A: in development (PHP)
Site B: http://www.apprenticesearch.com/

I want to include an input box on site A; after I type in the query and press Enter, open a new tab to display the search results of B. It would be as if I had typed the search query into B directly.

For example I searched for 'testing', and inspecting the search result from B, I see the following. How would I pass the query from site A to B?

```
<div id="search">
   <form action="/Resources/SiteSearch" id="siteSearchForm" method="post">
      <label for="search-box">
      SEARCH</label>
      <div id="search-box-wrapper">
         <input type="text" id="search-box">
      </div>
      <input id="searchText" name="searchText" type="hidden" value="testing"><input id="siteSearchUrl" name="siteSearchUrl" type="hidden" value="http://yboss.yahooapis.com/ysearch/limitedweb?format=xml&amp;sites=www.apprenticesearch.com&amp;q=testing">
      <input type="image" src="/userfiles/images/E/buttons/go.png" id="search-button" value="GO" siteurl="www.apprenticesearch.com"><!-- www.apprenticesearch.com -->
   </form>
</div>
```

Comment: connect to the database of B and run query on it.so u ll get the results from B

Comment: I don't think I need to do this (and wouldn't be able to anyway)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All you need to do is include a target="_blank" in the form on Site A, also the way that the request works on site B the siteSearchUrl input must be included

```
<form id="apprenticeForm" action="http://www.apprenticesearch.com/Resources/SiteSearch" method="POST" target="_blank" onsubmit='submitSearch()'>
    <input type="text" name="searchText" id="searchText" value=""/>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
    <input id="siteSearchUrl" name="siteSearchUrl" type="hidden" value="http://yboss.yahooapis.com/ysearch/limitedweb?format=xml&sites=www.apprenticesearch.com&q="/>
</form>
```

Like this http://jsfiddle.net/MVBLc/

---

After playing around with the form submitting, but the q parameter not being read by Site B, I believe it's because the input had escaped `&amp;` instead of '&'.

I've updated the HTML, and here's the javascript to update the field before submitting the form

```
function submitSearch()
{
    q = document.getElementById("searchText").value;
    document.getElementById("siteSearchUrl").value = 'http://yboss.yahooapis.com/ysearch/limitedweb?format=xml&sites=www.apprenticesearch.com&q=' + q; 
    return true;
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/MVBLc/2/)

The reason you need to use javascript for the additional input is the same reason why Site B uses javascript to populate siteSearchUrl in their [script](http://www.apprenticesearch.com/Scripts/apprenticesearch.js) before it sends the request.

Looking at how the server works: Site B sends that request to /Resources/SiteSearch where the `SiteSearch(String searchtext, String siteSearchUrl)` function gets called on their server. If you were to just go straight to that page with no post parameters you will find that a `System.ArgumentNullException Parameter name: uriString` is thrown for not having siteSearchUrl set from the server.

If you want to analyze the parameters of siteSearchUrl:

- The URL `yboss.yahooapis.com` is for [Yahoo's BOSS](http://developer.yahoo.com/boss/search/boss_api_guide/index.html) API servcie
- The `sites` parameter tells the API what site to search and display in the results
- and the `q` parameter is what query to search for

Comment: thanks! you've pointed me in the right direction... question now is how to append the correct search parameter when submitting the form. Do I need to use Javascript to constantly update the value of the q=xxx as the user is typing?

Comment: I tried something like this,

`<script type="text/javascript">
function updateSearch(){
 document.getElementById("siteSearchUrl").value = 'http://yboss.yahooapis.com/ysearch/limitedweb?format=xml&amp;sites=www.apprenticesearch.com&amp;q=' + document.getElementById("searchText").value
}
</script>`

Comment: Yes you need Javascript, I've updated my answer with code and another link to jsfiddle showing the fix to the siteSearchUrl problem.